# Office 365 MFA using code sent to email, instead of getting request on Microsoft Authenticator

Tags: azure, sharepoint, office365, multi-factor-authentication

I am working on a tenant which have 400++ sites, and we need to force this permission settings for external user sharing:-

**Set the share permissions on all sites to allow for only external users if they are invited by email and requires MFA for a code sent to their email to authenticate**

So is this something we can achieve? If the answer is Yes, then this need to be done on the site level or on the tenant level? If this need to be set on each site separately, then can we do this using Power shell? we can loop through all the sites inside the Power-shell, but how we can set this setting using Power shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email is not one of the available MFA options.

The following additional forms of verification can be used with Azure AD  -  Multi-Factor Authentication:

- Microsoft Authenticator app
- Windows Hello for Business
- FIDO2 security key
- OATH hardware token (preview)
- OATH software token
- SMS
- Voice call

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-mfa-howitworks#available-verification-methods